# Oracle Form12c Builder displaying blank page at runtime

Tags: java, oracle12c, oracleforms

When I try to run the form by clicking Program/Run form, it opens a webpage(explorer) and displays ORACLE FORMS label, but does not show the form only blank screen appear.
When I try to run the form by clicking Program/Run form, it opens a webpage(Chrome), but does not show the form only blank screen appear.

OS : Windows 7 64bit

Form : Oracle Form 12c

db : Oracle 12c locally

Browser : Chrome (up to date) and IE 11

JRE : jre1.8.0_131 (which is already installed with the JDK jdk1.8.0_131 as basic requirement to install weblogic to run oracle forms 12c)

btw I have tried to run the `test.fmb` form and i got same issue

I searched and found some people saying I have to run OC4J but it have not listed in the start menu and I also can not find it with the Middleware directory

AS I figure-out OC4J are used in old Oracle forms which replace by weblogic in oracle forms 12c is that right ??

thank you

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

There is a formsweb.cfg somewhere, if you change in this file the form you are trying to start it should work.

In chrome this won't work because oracle forms starts java.
Since a while ago chrome doesn't support NPAPI anymore so won't start any java process. Thats why your window stays blank.

Comment: i get error message that says `windows has blocked this software because it can't verify the publisher name: forms/ publisher: unknown publisher ` I have attached screenshot for the error message

Comment: I tried to solve it by following these instruction but it wont work out https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/windows-has-blocked-this-software-because-it-cant/2e60d481-b8a3-4a1a-af73-afcb5a3f2e36?tab=MoreHelp

Comment: I found that `formsweb.cfg` file at `C:\OracleMiddleware\user_projects\domains\base_domain\config‌​\fmwconfig\servers\W‌​LS_FORMS\application‌​s\formsapp_12.2.1\co‌​nfig` that file contains some of configuration as you said there is `form=test.fmx` that parameter is set to oracle test forms which I also tried run it before and I got same issue ... I also give it a try and changed some parameter to `form=account1.fmx` but left the `userid=null` and `host=null` and `port=null` because I am working locally and issue wont be sloved